# curl_exec: 1-5 seconds for execution time?

Tags: php, curl

In my php script I am using curl library and the function curl_exec takes 1-5 seconds to be executed ( and for some url it take 10 seconds as well ). It is normal ?

This is my script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;     
$url = "http://www.mashable.com/feed";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: The answer is yes, it is normal. If you add some more information about what you are using the cURL request for, we might be able to suggest a non-blocking solution or one that times out earlier.

Comment: I have just added my script above :)

Comment: Not much to add then. You could use `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to limit the maximum number of seconds cURL functions may execute. But since you want the contents of the file, you would not get any file content if such a timeout occurs. On a sidenote, if you are after a feed, why do you use cURL for this instead of a DOM or RSS parser?

Answer (score 0):

> It is normal ?

Totally depends on your connection, the target URLs, and the server it runs on. It's well possible that it's normal.

If you have command line access to your server, you could try replicating the actions in command line `curl` and see how long they take there; also try them from your local machine. If there are massive differences, there could be a networking or firewall issue.

But those kinds of loading times are not unheard of.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be uncommon - you are under the same conditions as if you requested an URL with your own browser - connecting and exchanging requests will take some time and if the URL you are requesting is busy or on a slower connection, the time naturally increases.